# Can I tweak this code to get what I want?

Tags: r

I have a df below:

```
d<-structure(list(ReviewType= c("Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Review","Review","Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction","Correction", "Correction", "Deficiency", "Deficiency", "Correction"), Submissiondate= c("2020-08-29 04:32:00","2020-08-28 04:31:00","2020-08-26 04:31:00","2020-08-25 04:31:00","2020-08-24 04:31:00","2020-08-23 04:31:00","2020-08-22 04:31:00","2020-08-21 04:31:00","2020-08-20 04:31:00","2020-08-19 04:31:00", "2020-09-27 04:31:00","2020-09-27 03:52:59","2020-09-28 17:30:00","2020-09-29 14:01:00", "2020-09-05 03:00:00","2020-09-05 03:51:00", "2020-09-03 23:59:49", "2020-09-02 00:03:54","2020-09-01 00:04:48" ), CaseNo= c("124","123","125","121","121","125","123","123","123","123","123","123","123","125","123","123","123","124","123")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -19L))

d<-d%>%arrange(CaseNo,Submissiondate)
```

I have a code like the one shown below:

```
d <- d %>% mutate(Submissiondate = as.Date(Submissiondate), 
                  weekday = wday(Submissiondate), 
                  week.end = Submissiondate + 7 - weekday) 


#1 End state for each case and week
EndStates <- d %>% group_by(CaseNo, week.end) %>% summarize(WeekEndState = last(ReviewType)) %>% ungroup()

#2 Get unique values of Case/Week.end/ReviewType
chk <- d %>%
  select(CaseNo, week.end, ReviewType) %>%
  distinct()

#3 Add the EndStates and count if the week had a correction AND the week ended as a Correction
chk <- left_join(chk, EndStates, by = c("CaseNo", "week.end"))
chk %>% 
  group_by(week.end, .drop = FALSE) %>%
  filter(WeekEndState == "Correction", ReviewType == "Correction") %>%
  summarize(n = n()) %>%
  ungroup()
```

This code is trying to see for each case number, what was its last status each week and only filtering for correction

The output for the code is shown below:

```
week.end       n
  <date>     <int>
1 2020-08-22     0
2 2020-08-29     1
3 2020-09-05     1
4 2020-10-03     1
```

However, i want to tweak this in a way that as long as the status for a case stayed at correction, it should be counted in the stats for all the subsequent weeks so in my df, i want the below output:

```
week.end       n
  <date>     <int>
1 2020-08-22     0
2 2020-08-29     1
3 2020-09-05     2
4 2020-10-03     2
```

It's 2 because case 121 stayed as correction and there was no subsequent update. Is this possible?

Edit:
A new df

```
d<-structure(list(ReviewType= c("Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Review","Review","Review","Review","Review","Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction","Correction", 
                                "Correction", "Deficiency", "Deficiency", "Correction","Correction","Deficiency","Correction"),
                  Submissiondate= c("2020-08-29 04:32:00","2020-08-28 04:31:00","2020-08-26 04:31:00","2020-08-25 04:31:00","2020-08-24 04:31:00","2020-08-23 04:31:00","2020-08-22 04:31:00","2020-08-21 04:31:00","2020-08-20 04:31:00","2020-08-19 04:31:00",
                                    "2020-09-27 04:31:00","2020-09-27 03:52:59","2020-09-28 17:30:00","2020-09-29 14:01:00",
                                    "2020-09-05 03:00:00","2020-09-05 03:51:00", "2020-09-03 23:59:49",
                                    "2020-09-02 00:03:54","2020-09-01 00:04:48","2020-10-01 04:31:00","2020-10-11 04:31:00","2020-10-21 04:31:00"),
                  CaseNo= c("124","123","125","121","121","125","123","123","123","123","123","123","123","125","123","123","123","124","123","127","127","127")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -22L))


d<-d%>%arrange(CaseNo,Submissiondate)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code do what you need:

```
# create a data frame with first week.end Date that a correction appears for 
# a CaseNo, and the day this correction is removed
correction_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=3, nrow=length(unique(chk$CaseNo))))
names(correction_df) <- c("CaseNo", "start", "finish")
for (i in 1:length(unique(chk$CaseNo))){
      n = unique(chk$CaseNo)[i]
      tmp = chk[chk$CaseNo==n,]
      correction_start = min(tmp$week.end[tmp$WeekEndState == "Correction"])
      correction_finish = min(tmp$week.end[tmp$WeekEndState != "Correction" &
                                                 tmp$week.end > correction_start])
      correction_df[i, ] <- c(n, correction_start,
                              correction_finish)
}

# count the number of correction cases "active" in each date in the data frame
asw = as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=2, nrow=length(unique(chk$week.end))))
names(asw) <- c("week.end", "n")
asw$week.end <- sort(unique(chk$week.end))
for (i in 1:length(unique(chk$week.end))){
      aDate = sort(unique(chk$week.end))[i]
      # n is the number of new correction cases in the week.end, minus the 
      # number of cases that changed their status from correction to something else
      n = sum(as.Date(as.numeric(correction_df$start),
                      origin="1970-01-01")==aDate, na.rm=T) - 
            sum(as.Date(as.numeric(correction_df$finish),
                        origin="1970-01-01")==aDate, na.rm=T)
      # finally, sum the accumulated cases with n
      asw$n[i] <- ifelse(i == 1, n, n+asw$n[i-1])
}
asw
```

**Edit:** another solution that considers the problem pointed out in the comment

```
# a data frame with dummies indicating if for a given week.end, the case
# refered in the col name ended as "Correction"
cor_df <- as.data.frame(matrix(ncol=length(unique(chk$CaseNo))+1, 
                               nrow=length(unique(chk$week.end))))
names(cor_df) <- c("week.end", unique(chk$CaseNo))
cor_df$week.end <- unique(chk$week.end)
for(i in 1:nrow(cor_df)){
      for(j in 2:ncol(cor_df)){
            this_CaseNo_idx = chk$CaseNo == strtoi(names(cor_df)[j])
            idx =  this_CaseNo_idx & 
                  chk$week.end == max(chk$week.end[chk$week.end <= cor_df$week.end[i] &
                                                         this_CaseNo_idx])
            if (sum(idx) < 1){
                  cor_df[i, j] = 0
            }
            else{
                  # The effect of the "max" here is that for CaseNo with duplicated
                  # records in the same day, it will always consider as it ended as
                  # "correction". To avoid this, change the code so only the latest
                  # record appear for each week.end in the chk data.frame
                  cor_df[i, j] = max(ifelse(chk$WeekEndState[idx] == "Correction" & 
                                              chk$ReviewType[idx] == "Correction", 
                                            1, 0))
            }
            
      }
}
cor_df$asw <- rowSums(cor_df[,2:ncol(cor_df)])
cor_df <- cor_df[order(cor_df$week.end),]
data.frame(week.end=cor_df$week.end, cor_df$asw)
```

Comment: So i tested a scenario in which a case goes from Correction in one week to deficiency in the next week causing it to drop off but then goes back to correction in the following week and this code is not taking that into consideration, do you know how to consider that? I have edited my question with a new df. Great code btw. Could not have thought of that in a million years

Comment: This code definitely works for the question i asked btw, thanks a lot

Comment: Yes, I can consider that, but in the case of a CaseNo with more than one occurrence in the same week.end, what should be considered (e.g. CaseNo 123 and date 2020-09-05)?

Comment: In that situation, only the status that's closest to the week.end. So if case moved from Correction to Deficiency to Correction in the same week then only the most latest correction should be considered. Just want to see how the status changes over the weeks.

Comment: I added another solution edditing the post. Hope it works.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! this is exactly what i need.

Comment: Can i ask what do you mean by change the code to only get the latest record if there's a duplicate record on the same day. I thought, chk$WeekEndState[idx] == "Correction" & 
                                              chk$ReviewType[idx] == "Correction" already does after we arrange(CaseNo,Submissiondate)

Comment: Sure. If you look at chk[chk$CaseNo == 123 & chk$week.end=="2020-09-05",] in your example dataset, there will be 2 rows returned. For this case, both rows have WeekEndState = Correction, but if for some CaseNo there are multiple rows for the same "week.end", and some of them have WeekEndState = Correction and other don't,  then it is ambiguous if they should be counted as Correction or not.

Comment: Hi Shinji, Thankful for your answer. Has already helped me and the company i work for a lot. Can i ask though, i am testing this on a data set with 5417191 observations (cases) and its 4 hours and plus. Is it stuck in a loop? Or the data is just that huge?

Comment: The nested loops are inefficient, and it would take a while for big data sets. To verify "where you are at", you can add print statements in the loop. The first solution I provided is faster, but needs to be modified as you pointed out. I suspect there would be a "tidy" solution for this too, but i'm unfamiliar with it.

Comment: Thanks though regardless for the help